# How can you show that there is destructive interference if Bragg‘s law is not fulfilled?

Tags: reflection, scattering, interference, diffraction, braggs-law

How can you show that there is destructive interference if Bragg‘s law is not fulfilled?

For a given angle $\phi$, spacing $d$ and wavelength $\lambda$: suppose that the path difference between the waves from first and second layer is e.g. $1.08 \lambda = 2 d \sin(\phi)$. This means, that the wave scattered from the second plane is shifted by $0.08 \lambda$ compared to the wave scattered from the first plane; the wave from the third plane is shifted by $0.16 \lambda$ compared to the wave from the first plane and so on. Now in my understanding, the wave coming from the second plane will be destructed (by destructive interference) only of there is a wave which is $(x + 0.58) \lambda$ shifted from the first wave (where $x$ is any integer), and so on.

How can I convince myself that there is for every wave always another wave so that they both mutually destructively interfere?